# Disadvantages of creating a volume with lvm instead of with libvirt? Storage pool present

Tags: lvm, libvirt

When creating the virtual machine on server A, virt-install created a libvirt-volume "VM" in the libvirt storage-pool "POOL".

```
 virsh-install --disk pool=POOL,size=$HDDSIZE,$DISKOPT -n VM
```

As expected, libvirt shows e.g.

```
# virsh vol-list POOL

Name                 Path
-----------------------------------------
VM                  /dev/VOLUMEGROUP/VM
anotherVM           /dev/VOLUMEGROUP/anotherVM
```

When migrating the virtual machine to server B, which does not share storage with server A, I instead created the logical volume with lvm:

```
 lvcreate -l $EXTNSIZE -n lvmVM VOLUMEGROUP
```

As *not* expected (but arguably expectable), libvirt on server B does **not** recognize lvmVM.

```
# virsh vol-list POOL

Name                 Path
-----------------------------------------
someOtherVM         /dev/VOLUMEGROUP/someOtherVM
```

I was able to manually start VM anyway. Fine. But...

- Are there dangers/disadvantages to leave libvirt in a blind state about the new volume inside POOL like this?
- e.g. will libvirt fail to auto-restart the VM on reboot etc.?

(or, from the other perspective: What is the gain in using libvirt volumes instead of just lvm volumes inside a storage pool, after the initial creation via e.g. virt-inst?)

- Is there a way to make libvirt recognize the volume?
- ... but would this recognition/conversion process write metadata into lvmVM and thus corrupt the VM virtual disk?

---

Details:

- On both servers, the lvm group "VOLUMEGROUP" is used for libvirt storage pool "POOL".
- On both servers, lvm shows the expected volume. Just the libvirt volume-"layer" is different.
- Debian Linux 8 x86_64, lvm2 2.02.111-2.2+deb8u1, libvirt 1.2.9-9+deb8u3
- size is 40 GB,  DISKOPT='bus=virtio,cache=writethrough,io=threads,sparse=false'
- beneath libvirt, KVM and qemu are used.
- libvirt xml for virtual machine "VM" has:

  ```
  disk type='block' device='disk' 
   driver name='qemu' type='raw'
   source dev='/dev/VOLUMEGROUP/VM'
   target dev='vda' bus='virtio'
  ```

Comment: What type of pool is "POOL"? It should be logical, then everything you create inside vg "VOLUMEGROUP" is automatically added to the pool. Check under /etc/libvirt/storage, there are your configuration xml files for your pools.

Comment: Pool type'=logical'. format type='lvm2'
But, as shown above, `virsh vol-list` does not show the new lvm volume.

Comment: try to refresh the pool: `virsh pool-refresh POOL` and then try `virsh vol-list` again because it should recognize the new lvm-volume

Comment: After `virsh pool-refresh POOL` the volume is visible. Thanks Broco!

Comment: No problem, I just logged into our server and found out that virsh doesn't refresh automatically when you create a volume. Btw, try the gui for Ubuntu, it's awesome.