# How to provision DRBD to libvirt storage pool?

Tags: kvm-virtualization, libvirt, drbd

I want to expose DRBD replicated storage (2 nodes Active/Passive) to libvirt as a storage pool for qcow2 files. However, I have the following error message:

```
virsh pool-create-as qcow2 --type=logical --target=/dev/drbd1
error: Failed to create pool qcow2
error: internal error: missing backend for pool type 3 (logical)
```

If I am using multipath device then the it has 0 capacity in the libvirt environment.

```
root@astranode0:/home/frolo# virsh pool-create-as qcow2 --type=mpath --target=/dev/mapper/vg1-qcow2 
setlocale: No such file or directory
Pool qcow2 created

root@astranode0:/home/frolo# virsh pool-info qcow2 
setlocale: No such file or directory
Name:           qcow2
UUID:           fa3b18a5-d849-43d9-86d2-96633367e8c7
State:          running
Persistent:     no
Autostart:      no
Capacity:       0.00 B
Allocation:     0.00 B
Available:      0.00 B
```

What I am doing wrong? I would appreciate any help! Thank you!

Comment: https://serverfault.com/questions/352641/how-can-i-use-the-hosts-lvm-vg-as-a-kvm-pool